# jQuery generating content from generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a database to create divs and then naming them from a field in a database.
Within this div is a "delete" link that I'd like to be able to create a div below the original div with a message such as "`are you sure you want to delete this?`"

But my issue comes to when the database has to generate more than one of these original divs, meaning that the "delete" link will be used more than once in different places or the different divs.

I am unsure on how to create a Javascript/jQuery script where it would:

```
1. check what the ID of the parent div is (div#parent -> ul -> li -> a).
2. generate a new div below the parent div (not inside).
3. once an option is selected, remove the generated div.
```

Heres an example of the layout that I'd like to work with:
[image: Example Layout]
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pQHY.png)

As you can see, the generated jQuery div would be outside of the parent div it also has the id of the parent div with "`_delete`" added onto the end. **The functions are there as an example for naming the functions...**

Would this be possible?

**EDIT - I have gotten it somewhat working, now the issue is when it creates the extra div it doesn't stop you from making more than one... How can I limit this?**

What I have done so far

```
function action() {
    var visable = false;
        if(visable==false) {
            $("#foo").append('
                <div id="action_foo" class="action-warn center">
                    Are you sure you want to delete "<span>foo</span>"? 
                    <a href="./?delete=1" onclick="deleteFoo()">Yes</a> / <a href="#" onclick="deleteFoo()">No</a>
                </div>
                ')
                visable = true;
        } else if(visable==true) {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#foo ul li.right').click(function(){
      var _parent = $(this).parent(), // gets immediate parent which is ul
          _gparent = _parent.parent(); // gets grandparent which is #foo
      $('<div id="foo_delete" class="action-warn center">-Delete Warning Text-</div>').insertAfter(_gparent); // insertAfter(); puts the content right after _gparent.
   });
   $('#foo_delete a').click(function(){
      $('#foo_delete').remove();
   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible.

1. `$('#foo_delete').sibling('#parent')` will allow you to select "parent".
   http://api.jquery.com/siblings/
2. Try using `insertAfter`.
   http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/
3. You can remove generated div also with `sibling`. 
   Try calling `$('#parent').sibling('#foo_delete').remove()` on parent's delete anchor.